# How to get all the versions of a bucket in Simperium

Tags: simperium

I'm doing this very simple app at http://lfschenone.com/ to learn how to use Simperium. I've gone through the basics, the content already synchronizes between browsers. The second step would be to show the previous versions of the content when the user clicks the "Previous" button (similar to Simplenote).

The documentation is of no help at all, so I've been looking at the source and found the methods `load_versions` and `get_version`, which seem very relevant. But I played with them for a while and got nothing except errors, falsities and empty arrays. Any pointers? Simple code examples would be greatly appreciated. You can find my whole code so far at http://lfschenone.com/tabula.js (it's very short!). Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can read the HTTP API docs for details, but basically you can add /v/ to the end of a GET request for an object to get any object version:
http://simperium.com/docs/reference/http/